# Multi Device Hybrid Apps Platform Views

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, visual-studio-2013, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I want to add "back button" panel for my app but only for iphones.
I am using vs2013 Multi Device Hybrid Apps plugin to develope mobile app. After a lot errors and problems I managed to start coding phase, the thing is android devices have panel to "back" or other stuff. But I need to set it also for iphones. Project has "merges" folder, I believe that part using for it. (I dont want to add that extra button for whole project, only iphone is enough for me as you know android devices have panel to "back" or other stuff.)
If its possible; how can I do that? Here is one of my page example ;

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Föy</title>
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnLogin").click(function () {
            window.location = "main.html";
        })
    });
</script> 
</head>
 <body>

<div class="container" id="login-block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-offset-4">
            <h3 class="animated bounceInDown">FÖY Fatura Ödeme Sistemleri</h3>
            <div class="login-box clearfix animated flipInY">
                <div class="login-logo">
                    <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Company Logo" /></a>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div class="login-form">
                    <div class="alert alert-error hide">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                        <h4>Hata!</h4>
                        İşlem Sırasında Hata Oluştu
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtUser" placeholder="Bayi Kodu" required />
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Şifre" required />
                        <button type="button" id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-red">GİRİŞ</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login-links">
                        <a href="forgot-password.html">
                            Şifremi Unuttum?
                        </a>
                        <br />
                        <a href="sign-up.html">
                            Bayi Değilim? <strong>Bayi Ol!</strong>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="social-login row">
                <div class="fb-login col-lg-6 col-md-12 animated flipInX">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-facebook btn-block"><strong>Facebook</strong> ile bağlan</a>
                </div>
                <div class="twit-login col-lg-6 col-md-12 animated flipInX">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-twitter btn-block"><strong>Twitter</strong> ile bağlan</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank You , Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your platform specific file within the `merges\ios\` folder and it should get picked up during build. More information and guidance can be found [here](http://photokandy.tumblr.com/post/47426024187/cordova-cli-simple-hooks-and-merges)